# How to display a non-default value in django-admin?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the `Model`:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=[["text", "Text"], ["choice", "Choice"]],
        max_length=6,
    )
    structure = models.JSONField(
        default=dict,
    )

    def get_default_structure(self) -> dict:
        if self.type == "text":
            return {"maxLength": None}
        if self.type == "choice":
            return {"variants": []}
        return dict()

@receiver(post_init, sender=Question)
def set_default_structure(sender: Type[Question],  **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs["instance"]
    if not instance.structure:
        instance.structure = instance.get_default_structure()
```

Also there is `Form` and `ModelAdmin`:

```py
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = "__all__"

@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = QuestionForm
```

By logic, after initializing an empty `Question`, the `structure` field should be overwritten, and it is.
But still the admin form for some reason displays the `{}` value gotten from `default=dict`.
Why does this happen and how can I make the `structure` widget display not the `{}` value, but the value taken from the `get_default_structure` method?

Answer (score 1):

Once the form is created and linked with an instance, it doesn't automatically detect subsequent changes made to the instance. So, when you use the `post_init` signal to update the structure, the form doesn't "see" this change. Perhaps explicitly setting the form's initial data to match the current state of the model instance, fixes it.

For this you can you can override the `__init__` method of your form to update the structure field's initial value based on the instance's type.

```py
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and not self.instance.structure:
            self.initial['structure'] = self.instance.get_default_structure()
```

Comment: I actually tried that too, but it didn't work. I didn't find out the exact cause of the problem, but when creating an empty form it didn't create a new instance, it just takes the class fields. So I had to change the `default` of the field so that it would generate a ready value depending on the `default` of `Question.type`.